# Changing DragEffect when moving out of my form

Tags: c#, winforms, draggable

I have a form which contains components that can be drag out my form to be on their own.

On the **QueryContinueDrag** event of my components, If the QueryContinueDragEventArgs.Action is Drop I test if my component is In the active form. If not, I create a new form and y put it in at the location of my cursor.

The problem is, the dragEffect indicates that I can't drop out the form. Is there any way I can change this?

Can't post much code here, cause it's way more complexe than just this. But if needed I'll try to do a simple project that show my issue.

Comment: You can change the Cursor while Dragging something. Try this in QueryContinueDrag: `switch (e.Action) { case DragAction.Continue: if (!this.Bounds.Contains(MousePosition)) { Cursor.Current = Cursors.Help; } break; case DragAction.Drop: if (!this.Bounds.Contains(MousePosition)) { /* new Form */ } break; }` You could do the ~same in GiveFeedback, checking the Cursor position and set `e.UseDefaultCursors = false; Cursor.Current = Cursors.Help;` if the position falls outside the bounds, otherwise `e.UseDefaultCursors = true;`  (cannot test right now, see how it goes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi):

You can change the Cursor while Dragging something.

Try this in QueryContinueDrag:

```
switch (e.Action)
{
    case DragAction.Continue:
        if (!this.Bounds.Contains(MousePosition))
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Help;
        break;
    case DragAction.Drop:
        if (!this.Bounds.Contains(MousePosition))
        {
            // new Form
        }
        break;
}
```

You could do the same in `GiveFeedback`, checking the Cursor position, and set `e.UseDefaultCursors = false; Cursor.Current = Cursors.Help;` if the position falls outside the bounds, otherwise `e.UseDefaultCursors = true;`.